# Why my scp is working one side only? "Lost connection" SCP transfer

Tags: ssh, backup, connection, scp

I'm trying to transfer a file via ssh but it works only from PC1 to PC2 but it doesn't work backwards.

I've checked my ssh_config files and both are the same. Which is basic:

```
Host *
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts 
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Because i've also trying adding this to the recievers `ssh_config`

```
PasswordAuthentication no
Port 22
Protocol 2, 1
```

And it still doesn't work.

Here's my I/O

```
:~# scp -v testFile.txt user@192.168.1.67:/home
```

> ```
> Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 192.168.1.67, user root, command scp -v -t /home
> OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
> debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
> debug1: Applying options for *
> debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.67 [192.168.1.67] port 22.
> debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.67 port 22: Connection refused
> ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.67 port 22: Connection refused
> lost connection
> ```

What am I missing?

Comment: my Firewall is Disabled

Comment: You Are you sure SSH is still running on that machine?  BTW, you should consider upgrading Debian 5 is end of life.

Comment: @Zoredache I checked that sshd is running with `ps aux | grep sshd` also, I'm using this debian because upgrading to 6 gave me some troubles on this special server..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your given output it looks like your host isn't accepting connections on port 22.

`ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.67 port 22: Connection refused`

Check your firewall configuration and make sure it's allowing ssh connections on port 22 from all locations.

Also make sure that you restarted `sshd` after making changes to `sshd_config`.

You can do this by running `service sshd restart` or `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`

If you need any further help, post the output of `iptables -L`

Comment: I forgot to say that i've already disabled Firewall

Comment: yes. That was the problem. Just enabled `PasswordAuthentication yes` in the `sshd_config` file. Thankyou!